# SQL Server - deduplicate and return table with single address

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am a bit stuck with this one.

I have the following situation:

```
Table
----------------------------------------
ID  | Street         | Zipcode | Surname 
----------------------------------------
001 |Summer Street 2 | 0001    | Smith
002 |Summer Street 2 | 0001    | Smith
003 |Winter Street 1 | 0002    | Muller
004 |Autumn Street 5 | 0004    | Jones
005 |Winter Street 1 | 0002    | Muller
```

Final Table should de-duplicate, it does not really matter which of the duplicate ids is chosen:

```
----------------------------------------
ID  | Street         | Zipcode | Surname 
----------------------------------------
001 |Summer Street 2 | 0001    | Smith
003 |Winter Street 1 | 0002    | Muller
004 |Autumn Street 5 | 0004    | Jones
```

I am able to select all duplicates by the following statement and store it in another. But I don´t know how to proceed from here ti get to the desired final table. As well I have the feeling that working with three tables at the end is a dirty solution.

```
SELECT
Address,
Postcode,
Surname
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
   Address, 
   Postcode, 
   Surname
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

It is important to know that I am only allowed start statements with Select.

Comment: "working with three tables at the end is a dirty solution", what do you mean by that? Also, are you wanting to create a new table based on the SELECT query that removes the duplicates?

Comment: I have the feeling that this problem can be solved more performant than using three tables. The idea from Aaron seems to work with two tables.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a little CTE "magic":

```
WITH Dups AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Address], Postcode, Surname
                              ORDER BY ID) AS RN
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT *
FROM Dups
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Yes @Larnu, but that statement doesn't begin with Select as the op stated is a requirement.

Comment: Apologies, thought the OP wanted the `DELETE`the dups. Have changed to a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are always perfect duplicates except for the `ID`, just use an aggregate on `ID` to choose one of the rows.  For example `MIN()`:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, Address, Postcode, Surname
FROM Table
GROUP BY Address, Postcode, Surname
```

Edit:  A little extra explanation:

The only difference in your duplicate rows is the `ID` column, otherwise they are identical.  If you use an aggregate function, such as `MIN()` which chooses the minimum value, and `GROUP BY` the other columns, then you will no longer have duplicates in your result set.

These rows:

```
001 |Summer Street 2 | 0001 | Smith
002 |Summer Street 2 | 0001 | Smith
```

Will group and roll up to this row:

```
001 |Summer Street 2 | 0001 | Smith
```

Because `001` is the `MIN(ID)` between the two.

Note: This approach isn't always possible if you need a specific `ID`, but since you said it doesn't matter which row is chosen, this is the simplest way.

Comment: You are correct @Aaron Dietz, I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @ aaron dietz This seems to work in a first test. I have to finally validate and will give feedback. I have to say I do not really understand what it does, but results looking good.

Comment: @crow_doe Happy to help, I've added an explanation which should clear things up a bit.

Comment: It is taking the minimum `ID` for a given row. Because the other fields are identical, i.e. only `ID` differs, the MIN() aggregate function is only returning `ID` = 1.

Comment: @aaron dietz Thank you again for your explanation. This clears it up for me. Great!

Answer (score 0):

If your permissions are set so that you can only "...start statements with Select" I do not believe you will be able to do this. You need to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [final].[table]
            ([Address]
             , [Postcode]
             , [Surname])
    SELECT [Address]
           , [Postcode]
           , [Surname]
    FROM   [Table]
    GROUP  BY [Address]
              , [Postcode]
              , [Surname]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```